# Adding "an" or not, when describing different medical conditions - are there rules?

Tags: articles, medical

First off, I'll admit that attempting to codify the use of "a" & "the" could easily drive a person insane. I hope you'll forgive me for asking such a question.
However, I've got a specific situation for which I hope some solid rules can be found.
I have an ESL student who's studying to be a Japanese/English medical interpreter.

I can't seem to figure out a set of rules for when to add "a/an" to a medical condition, and when not to.

At first I thought I had it figured out, as follows:

If it's a single occurrence of the condition and/or if it's in a specific part of the body, then use a/an:

- A knee ache
- An aneurysm
- A tumor

However, if it's systemic or can't be pinned down to a fairly specific part of the body, then don't use an article:

- Cancer
- Diabetes
- Heartburn

But this system breaks down when I consider that we say "chest pain", although it's a single condition that's specific to an area, while at the same time saying "tonsillitis" which is singular and in a very specific area.

I think (or hope) I'm missing a useful delimiter, here. Can anyone think of one??

Comment: I think it's mostly ideosyncratic and idiomatic, there aren't general rules.

Comment: Ack!! My worst fear! 

Comment: Better get used to it, English is full of stuff like that.

Comment: To make it worse someone could be said to have either "cancer or "a cancer" depending on context. For instance the same  patient at the same stage  could be described as having "lung cancer" or "a cancer in his left lung".

Comment: Thank you both for the reassurance of sorts. I wanted to be sure I wasn't letting my student down, by not giving her a concrete set of rules. But, as you've pointed out, perhaps she may just have to learn from experience, until such time as the correct choice can be "felt". Oh, English.....!